# how to extend Stream by implementing tailDefined

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections

I'd like to extend `scala.Stream`.  When I try, it tells me I can't, because I don't have the required method `tailDefined`.

```
class S[T](s:Stream[T]) extends Stream[T] {

}
```

When I try this, it tells me `tailDefined` is protected:

```
class S[T](s:Stream[T]) extends Stream[T] {
  def tailDefined = s.tailDefined
}
```

How do I get around this limitation and implement an extension of `Stream`?

Comment: did you notice "warning: inheritance from class Stream in package immutable is deprecated"? so even if you manage to get this working now, it won't work in a future Scala.

Comment: Thanks @SethTisue.  How would you (functionally) extend `Stream` then?

Comment: It depends on your motivation for wanting to extend `Stream`. If you want to add new operations, see Alexey's answer. Else, consider using composition rather than inheritance. To give a better answer, we'd need to know more about your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "add new methods" to `Stream`, use implicit classes:

```
implicit class S[T](s:Stream[T]) {
  def method1 = ...
}

val s: Stream[Int] = ...
s.method1
```