# Extending Scala Stream

Tags: scala

Is it possible to extend the Stream class to add extra functionality like following?

```
case class CloseableStream[T](stream:Stream[T], closeables: Seq[AutoCloseable]) extends Stream[T] {
  def close = ???
  /*wrapper functions of Stream[T]*/
}
```

I need the interface to be the same as Stream. When I inherit from Stream it requires me to implement a method `tailDefined` which is protected and hence I cannot exactly wrap the stream inside the new class. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you describe the functionality you are trying to add?

Comment: Did you try implicit class?

Comment: Why not use implicits to "enhance my library": `implicit class CloseableStream[T](stream:Stream[T])
                       (implicit closeables: Seq[AutoCloseable]) {
  def close = ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490665/how-to-extend-stream-by-implementing-taildefined

Comment: @jwvh if I understand correctly this changes the interface, while if I could extend stream it won't break any user code.. I was trying to avoid that..

Comment: @rah, "changes the interface"? Well yes, it adds `close` as a method that can be invoked from a `Stream`.  Isn't that what you're looking for? How would that "break any user code"?  Study [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/1732/implicits#t=201608301546444953202) to understand how implicit classes are used to enhance existing data types.

Comment: @jwvh for it to work, the user code has to declare an implicit variable which he does not have any clue how to construct and the library cannot provide the implicits as it is different for each instance of stream and is associated with it. Sorry I am new to scala and most likely I am being dumb. I'll brush up the implicits

Comment: @rah the user will not have to declare an implicit variable, but they may need to do an additional import to get the `close` functionality. Check out StackOverflow Documentation on implicit classes: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/1732/implicits/7538/implicit-classes#t=201608301714221723006